# Everything related to everything

Tags: django

I'm trying to put together a system where certain models are all related to each other, and can be modified in each others change form within the admin.

An example would be `Person A` being related to `Event A` and `Event B`, and when editing either `Event A` or `Event B` you'd be able to see, modify, and order `Person A`.

Initially I did this with one super relations table which I used as a through table. This table consisted of a foreign key to each model type. I then used django admin inlines using this relations table which gave me a solution to my example. This also allowed me to have separate inlines for each model type so it is easy to manage.

The problem I'm having though is I can't have `Event A` directly related to `Event B` because I'm missing the two `Event` foreign keys on my relations table.

Is there a way to solve the self relations using the super table, or is there another method I should be using?

To explain things a little clearer, here are a couple of images that explain what I'm trying to do. Basically I want to see `Person 1` as a relation to the objects `Person 1` is attached to.

[image: Person 1 relations]

[image: Article 1 relations]

The above is using the generic foreign key as a parent field for the relations, but this creates unique records and doesn't let me alter the relation from a related item.

Comment: [Generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) are probably what you want.

Comment: Generic relations don't really work, as they create unique records per object, meaning I can't go back to another object and see the reverse of the relation.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the exact problem you're having. With `GenericForeignKey` on your super table and `GenericRelation` defined on your (`Event` and `Person`) models, you can traverse in both directions. Instead of having `Tag`s pointing at one object, you have `Relation`s pointing at two objects (so you'd have 2x3 fields on your model). Since the relation is generic (you can point to any object of any model class), it can join a person to an event, but also an event to an another event.

Comment: The generic foreign key works for parent assignment with the relations being the other foreign keys, but the goal is to be able to assign `Bar1` and `Bar2` to `Foo1` through an inline admin, and then on the change form of `Bar1` to be able to see `Foo1` as an inline too. With the generic parent all records within my relation table are unique to that object rather than being editable from both sides.